# Product catalog with video for joomla

Tags: video, joomla2.5

I want to use a product catalogue extension in which I could display the following:

1.Product Title/Desc
2.Product Image
3.Product Detail Page Link
4.Product Video

As I am new to joomla, I could not find out what I have been looking for.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not available in any extension. But you can try using redSHOP component. It is available in Joomla extension list. You need a bit customization  At back end you can add custom field. there you can select field title like video then kind of field single select and so not. i hope this will work.